# WinAPI32 Hello World

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Создал проект Win32, в нем файл,хочу сделать hello world, можете дать исходник?(Visual C++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот, например, по [ссылке с википедии](http://www2.latech.edu/~acm/helloworld/visualc++.html) из статьи «Hello World»:

- hello.cpp:

  ```
  // hello.cpp : Defines the class behaviors for the application.
  //

  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "hello.h"
  #include "hellodlg.h"

  #ifdef _DEBUG
  #undef THIS_FILE
  static char BASED_CODE THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
  #endif

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CHelloApp

  BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CHelloApp, CWinApp)
          //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CHelloApp)
          //}}AFX_MSG
          ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, CWinApp::OnHelp)
  END_MESSAGE_MAP()

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CHelloApp construction

  CHelloApp::CHelloApp()
  {
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // The one and only CHelloApp object

  CHelloApp theApp;

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CHelloApp initialization

  BOOL CHelloApp::InitInstance()
  {
          // Standard initialization

          Enable3dControls();
          LoadStdProfileSettings();  // Load standard INI file options (including MRU)

          CHelloDlg dlg;
          m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
          int nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
          if (nResponse == IDOK)
          {
          }
          else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
          {
          }

          // Since the dialog has been closed, return FALSE so that we exit the
          //  application, rather than start the application's message pump.
          return FALSE;
  }
  ```
- hellodlg.cpp

  ```
  // hellodlg.cpp : implementation file
  //

  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "hello.h"
  #include "hellodlg.h"

  #ifdef _DEBUG
  #undef THIS_FILE
  static char BASED_CODE THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
  #endif

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CHelloDlg dialog

  CHelloDlg::CHelloDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
          : CDialog(CHelloDlg::IDD, pParent)
  {
          //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CHelloDlg)
                  // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add member initialization here
          //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
          m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
  }

  void CHelloDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
  {
          CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
          //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CHelloDlg)
                  // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add DDX and DDV calls here
          //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
  }

  BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CHelloDlg, CDialog)
          //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CHelloDlg)
          ON_WM_PAINT()
          ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
          //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
  END_MESSAGE_MAP()

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CHelloDlg message handlers

  BOOL CHelloDlg::OnInitDialog()
  {
          CDialog::OnInitDialog();
          CenterWindow();

          // TODO: Add extra initialization here

          return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
  }

  // If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
  //  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
  //  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

  void CHelloDlg::OnPaint() 
  {
          if (IsIconic())
          {
                  CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

                  SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, (WPARAM) dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0);

                  // Center icon in client rectangle
                  int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
                  int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
                  CRect rect;
                  GetClientRect(&rect);
                  int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
                  int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

                  // Draw the icon
                  dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
          }
          else
          {
                  CDialog::OnPaint();
          }
  }

  HCURSOR CHelloDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
  {
          return (HCURSOR) m_hIcon;
  }
  ```
- hello.h

  ```
  // hello.h : main header file for the HELLO application
  //

  #ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
          #error include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH
  #endif

  #include "resource.h"           // main symbols

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CHelloApp:
  // See hello.cpp for the implementation of this class
  //

  class CHelloApp : public CWinApp
  {
  public:
          CHelloApp();

  // Overrides
          // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
          //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CHelloApp)
          public:
          virtual BOOL InitInstance();
          //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

  // Implementation

          //{{AFX_MSG(CHelloApp)
          //}}AFX_MSG
          DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
  };


  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ```
- hellodlg.h

  ```
  // hellodlg.h : header file
  //

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // CHelloDlg dialog

  class CHelloDlg : public CDialog
  {
  // Construction
  public:
          CHelloDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);        // standard constructor

  // Dialog Data
          //{{AFX_DATA(CHelloDlg)
          enum { IDD = IDD_HELLO_DIALOG };
                  // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add data members here
          //}}AFX_DATA

          // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
          //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CHelloDlg)
          protected:
          virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);        // DDX/DDV support
          //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

  // Implementation
  protected:
          HICON m_hIcon;

          // Generated message map functions
          //{{AFX_MSG(CHelloDlg)
          virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
          afx_msg void OnPaint();
          afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
          //}}AFX_MSG
          DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
  };
  ```
- resource.h

  ```
  //{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
  // Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
  // Used by HELLO.RC
  //
  #define IDR_MAINFRAME                                   128
  #define IDD_HELLO_DIALOG                                102

  // Next default values for new objects
  // 
  #ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
  #ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

  #define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        129
  #define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32771
  #define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1000
  #define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
  #endif
  #endif
  ```
- hello.rc

  ```
  //Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
  //
  #include "resource.h"

  #define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
  //
  #include "afxres.h"

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  #undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS


  #ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // TEXTINCLUDE
  //

  1 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
  BEGIN
      "resource.h\0"
  END

  2 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
  BEGIN
      "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
      "\0"
  END

  3 TEXTINCLUDE DISCARDABLE 
  BEGIN
      "#include ""res\\hello.rc2""  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
      "\r\n"
      "#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES\r\n"
      "#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES\r\n"
      "#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES\r\n"
      "#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES\r\n"
      "#include ""afxres.rc""  // Standard components\r\n"
      "\0"
  END

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  #endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Icon
  //

  IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON    DISCARDABLE     "res\\hello.ico"

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Dialog
  //

  IDD_HELLO_DIALOG DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 185, 92
  STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
  CAPTION "Hello, World"
  FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
  BEGIN
      DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,129,6,50,14
      PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,129,23,50,14
      LTEXT           "Hello, World!",IDC_STATIC,5,34,113,8
  END


  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Version
  //

  VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
   FILEVERSION 1,0,0,1
   PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,1
   FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
  #ifdef _DEBUG
   FILEFLAGS 0x1L
  #else
   FILEFLAGS 0x0L
  #endif
   FILEOS 0x4L
   FILETYPE 0x1L
   FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
  BEGIN
      BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          BLOCK "040904B0"
          BEGIN
              VALUE "CompanyName", "\0"
              VALUE "FileDescription", "HELLO MFC Application\0"
              VALUE "FileVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1\0"
              VALUE "InternalName", "HELLO\0"
              VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright \251 1996\0"
              VALUE "LegalTrademarks", "\0"
              VALUE "OriginalFilename", "HELLO.EXE\0"
              VALUE "ProductName", "HELLO Application\0"
              VALUE "ProductVersion", "1, 0, 0, 1\0"
          END
      END
      BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
      BEGIN
          VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
      END
  END



  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // String Table
  //

  STRINGTABLE DISCARDABLE 
  BEGIN
      ID_INDICATOR_EXT        "EXT"
      ID_INDICATOR_CAPS       "CAP"
      ID_INDICATOR_NUM        "NUM"
      ID_INDICATOR_SCRL       "SCRL"
      ID_INDICATOR_OVR        "OVR"
      ID_INDICATOR_REC        "REC"
  END


  #ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  // Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
  //
  #include "res\hello.rc2"  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources

  #define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES
  #define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES
  #define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES
  #define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES
  #include "afxres.rc"  // Standard components

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  #endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
  ```

Comment: Ну, это сразу MFC, а ТС хотел небось чистый WinAPI.